# How to handle a bounded combobox where selected value can be null?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, data-binding

I have the following to database tables:

```
**Product**
idProject int not null (PK)
ProductDescription Varchar not null
ProductCategory int null (reference to idCategory, however null values are allowed)

**Category** 
idCategory int not null (PK)
CategoryName varchar not null
```

In an application to edit these tables object using databound controls.

[image]

`TextBox1.Text` and `TextBox2.Text` is bound to `projectBindingSource - idProject` and `projectBindingSource - ProjectDescription`. The `projectBindingSource` over data member *Project* is navigated by `bindingNavigator1` component.

ComboBox1 is bound to `CategoryBindingSource` component over data member *Categroy* with value member *idCategory* and display member *CategoryName*. Selected Value references `projectBindingSource - idCategory`.

The problem, when navigating over a data row with a null values in `ProjectCategory` is that the the first value in data member *Categroy* is displayed instead of an unselected combobox. I would expect the latter.

Note:

- this is a watered down representation of the actual problem.
- my sollution to the problem below, but what is the correct way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with, but this seems very cumbersome.

```
DataTable categories = view.ToTable("Categories", true, "idCategory", "CategoryName");
categories .Columns["idCategory"].AllowDBNull = true;
DataRow defualtrow = sitecategoriestable.NewRow();
defualtrow = categories.NewRow();
defualtrow["idCategory"] = DBNull.Value;
defualtrow["CategoryName"] = "No Value Selected";
categories.Rows.InsertAt(defualtrow, 0);
ComboBox1.DataSource = categories;
ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "CategoryName";
ComboBox1.ValueMember = "idCategory";
```